# Creating sprites in programming

Tags: php, javascript, image-processing, sprite

I'm making a game in HTML5 and Javascript using canvas. I have successfully created the basic structure: moving the map, objects and sprites.

For the animation of the character, I use sprites ([like this example](http://www.d-grafix.com/gfx/walk_iso.jpg)) and I would also like to allow the user to customize his character so he can choose between different types of eyes, hair, clothes, etc - how it is often seen in many games.

Knowing that the user has chosen certain hair, eyes and clothes, how can I create a sprite image for them with PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP interface to graphic libraries like GD or ImageMagick to merge pieces into single images. Alternatively you can simply draw all separate pieces at coordinates of player, so player will consist from several sprites, not just one and move them all at once. This way you can save on storing big amount of recombinations possible with your pieces and don't have to introduce delay when server-side have to generate new combined image.